Hyper-V. После смены сетевого адаптера в виртуальном коммутаторе пропал инет в виртуалке на Ubuntu Server 22.04.4
Всем добра!
Имеется хост (192.168.0.100) с Windows 11 на борту и гипервизором Hyper-V. После переезда на другую квартиру пришлось подключить компьютер к инету по WiFi вместо провода, и после этого отвалилась сеть на виртуалке

Вводные:

Подключился к WiFi
Сменил адаптер в виртуальном коммутаторе Hyper-V
В адаптерах на хосте появился мост (когда использовался провод такого не было)

Включил виртуальную машину
Роутер виртуалку не увидел

При этом виртуалка получила старый ip (статика на виртуалке не прописана)
Во время включения eth0 поднимается быстро и не выдаёт ошибок
root@portainer:~# ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe00:6401  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:00:64:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 720  bytes 52160 (52.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 563  bytes 39892 (39.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


С хоста пинг на виртуалку (192.168.0.104) идёт, по ssh коннектит, в веб сервисы развёрнутые на виртуалке пускает (по ip)
С виртуалки пинг на хост не идёт

PING 192.168.0.100 (192.168.0.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.100 ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 16373ms


пинг на гугл (8.8.8.8)

root@portainer:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.104 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.104 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.104 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 9203ms
pipe 4

Интернета разумеется нет

Теперь конфиги:
/etc/resolv.conf:
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53

/etc/network/interfaces:
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


route -n:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-7224601463ca
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9a27e8687303
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-1d435b4c76c1
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-da82d04fe72d
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-eac021e7fa8b
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-1038f898fee7
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-c5f020b50ae0
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d510171d115d
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

arp -a:
? (192.168.0.100) at 84:14:4d:10:53:29 [ether] on eth0
? (172.17.0.5) at 02:42:ac:11:00:05 [ether] on docker0
? (172.25.0.2) at 02:42:ac:19:00:02 [ether] on br-d510171d115d
? (192.168.0.1) at <incomplete> on eth0
? (172.17.0.4) at 02:42:ac:11:00:04 [ether] on docker0
? (172.17.0.3) at 02:42:ac:11:00:03 [ether] on docker0

Совсем не понимаю почему не работает... Надеюсь на вашу помощь
Толь лыжи не едут, толь я – долбанутый

Что то мне подсказывает, что когда в виртуальном свиче указываешь wifi адаптер, он строит маршруты через хоста а не через роутер
но как это фиксить я хз

как я и предполагал виртуальный свич hyper-v строит маршруты через хоста а не через роутер.
юзаем lan
